# GLib, is there a reliable way to test icons existence ? (Vala)

Tags: glib, vala

Typically, I’m gathering info of steam games, which does create game icons if user asked it. So there might be icons for games available like `steam_icon_1524` but not for sure.

How could I test if an icon is available ?

Comment: This is a bit light on details for anyone to be able to answer.  Where are you getting the list of games? How does Steam store icons? Is there a non-Vala way to get the information? It sounds like this is more of a Steam question than Vala or GLib…

Comment: This question is valid for any icon... also steam games are stored in ```.steam/SteamApps/```, in **pseudo json or pseudo yaml files**, not sure. Steam may store icons - in ```.steam/games/```, in **zip files**, and **managing icons in place of steam is not a good idea** since games can be removed and so long - , but if you **make an icon on desktop (via steam only), he will provide game icon system wide**. Again this is **valid for any icon**, and there is **no steam solution**, otherwise I would not be asking even if this is a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer may not hold for steam games, but you said it's not specific to steam, so *shrug*.

Basically, you just need to call [GLib.AppInfo.get_icon](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gio-2.0/GLib.AppInfo.get_icon).  It will return null if there is no icon.

To enumerate installed applications you use `GLib.AppInfo.get_all ()`.

Under the hood, what is happening is that the *.desktop files stored in the applications/ subdirectory of `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` (fallback if not set: "/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/") and `$XDG_HOME_DATA_DIR` (fallback if not set: "~/.local/share/") are parsed (see [Desktop Entry Specification](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec/) for details on the file format), and the "Icon" key is used determine the icon name.

Technically, this doesn't quite tell you whether or not the icon actually exists with the current icon theme, only if it is *supposed* to exist.  That's where the [Icon Theme Specification](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Specifications/icon-theme-spec/) comes in.  There are several implementations, but since you're using Vala I'll assume you're using GTK+…

You can use [Gtk.IconTheme.get_default](http://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.IconTheme.get_default.html) to get the theme, then [Gtk.IconTheme.lookup_by_gicon](http://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.IconTheme.lookup_by_gicon.html) to get the [Gtk.IconInfo](http://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.IconInfo.html) (or null if it wasn't found).

Putting it all together, here is a quick program to list all the installed applications and their icons:

```
private static void main (string[] args) {
  Gtk.init (ref args);

  unowned Gtk.IconTheme theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default ();

  foreach (unowned GLib.AppInfo appinfo in GLib.AppInfo.get_all ()) {
    GLib.Icon? icon = appinfo.get_icon ();
    if (icon != null && icon is GLib.ThemedIcon) {
      GLib.message ("%s: %s", appinfo.get_display_name (), icon.to_string ());
      Gtk.IconInfo? iconinfo = theme.lookup_by_gicon (icon, 48, 0);
      if (iconinfo != null) {
        GLib.message (iconinfo.get_filename ());
      } else {
        GLib.message ("No icon.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While this is not the answer i would need, it does answer the actual question, and btw tells me there is no reliable way to check steam icons like you pointed out. However it does answer the question "GLib, is there a reliable way to test icons existence ?" so thank you for that :p